# TexStudio cant find .aux file

Tags: texlive, texstudio, glossaries, auxiliary-files

I am new to LaTeX offline compilers and editors (I used Overleaf before, so with LaTeX language itself - I am pretty comfortable). I am unable to make simple glossary. I use TexStudio and TexLive. Everytime I try to run pdflatex it compiles my file without printing the glossary (that is ok). Now all that is left to do is run glossary command using F9. Now it is supposed to create glossary file and then once I recompile again it should print out the glossary in my pdf.

This is the code that I try to compile:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Load the package
\usepackage{glossaries}

% Generate the glossary
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

%Term definitions
\newglossaryentry{utc}{name=UTC, description={Coordinated Universal Time}}
\newglossaryentry{adt}{name=ADT, description={Atlantic Daylight Time}}
\newglossaryentry{est}{name=EST, description={Eastern Standard Time}}

% Use the terms
\gls{utc} is 3 hours behind \gls{adt} and 10 hours ahead of \gls{est}.

%Print the glossary
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

However when I try to create Glossary file using F9, I get this error message:

```
Process started: makeglossaries.exe "glossary"

Auxiliary file 'glossary.aux' doesn't exist. Have you run LaTeX? C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 2: perl c:\texlive\2020\texmf-dist\scripts\glossaries\makeglossaries glossary

Process exited with error(s)
```

I checked the folder with .tex file and .aux file is present there. So it is probably wrong path settings? However I checked documentation and Glossary command is supposed to look for .aux file in the directory of the .tex file. If that was the case I wouldnt get the error since I do have .aux file in the directory of a .tex file.

My OS is `Windows 10`.

TeXLive version is probably `TeX 3.14159265` (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)'
TexLive is installed in `C:\texlive` path.

Version of TeXStudio is `3.0.1` and it is installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\texstudio` path.

I also add some screenshots of config and my folder with .aux file

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: 0

I checked your MWE and it runs for me, so the problem is not in the code. Why have you defined your own make glossary command btw? (not that it should matter)

Comment: Where you call the executable glossary program, try to add the extension explicitly after the `%`. Observe that other commands use this approach, such as `makeindex %.idx` for example.

Comment: Well good quesiton. I made it because I didnt know there was a Glossary option already included in Texstudio. However I already managed to get it going. I believe the problem was me using folders with nonlatin signs in them - 'ř' sign in particular. When .exe tried to change directory he did not have proper encoding, so instead path C:\example\ř the path became C:\example\? and it couldnt perform cd with this path. After moving .tex files into different folder, it works great. If you would like to, post a solution and I will mark it. Thanks for your help here and also in my previous post.

Comment: Well, good. I don't think I have a full answer. You can post one if you wish.

Comment: @DanielŘehák You figured it out yourself, so it is your solution! Have you checked whether the ř is also the root to the problem for the compiling issue in general?

Comment: I am not sure. I did a factory reset and now it works just fine. I do not even want to try it since if it was the case, the whole factory reset was useless.

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to get it going. I believe the problem was in me using folders with nonlatin signs in them - 'ř' sign in particular. When .exe tried to change directory it did not have proper encoding, so instead path C:\example\ř the path became C:\example? and it couldnt perform cd with this path. After moving .tex files into different folder, it works great.